# how to remove array key from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [food_item_id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [food_item_id] => 6 ) )
```

from this array, I need the numbers only, I dont want another datas in the array in codeigniter.

Comment: Do you mean `1` and `6` as numbers? (= values)

Comment: `$another_array = array_values($array)`

Comment: array_column($your_array, 'food_item_id')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$result = array_column($array, 'food_item_id');
```

Comment: Excellent simple suggestion to a poorly worded question.